# Bluetooth on/off button missing but my device is still showing with the button greyed out. Crazy frustrating

Tags: performance, bluetooth

All of a sudden, my bluetooth on/off button disappeared from the bluetooth settings window. My bluetooth device is still there, but the button are greyed out so I can neither remove the device or connect. I've tried all the typical advices given over the net (device manager, airplane mode, start settings etc. etc. I even went into my registry and searched everything with the name of my bluetooth device and deleted it just in case it was the problem but to no avail.

Everything was working absolutely brilliant until all of a sudden one day I disconnected because I wanted to use the device on my phone (which it still works fine on my phone by the way). The on/off button just disappeared and the buttons on my pc just greyed out.

I have bent my mind trying to figure this out but I have gone nuts. I've included a screentshot. Please help! Thanks kindly to all who try! Here is a link to the pic!

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to make it more concise.  WAY TOO MUCH INFORMATION.  `The on/off button just disappeared and the buttons on my pc just greyed out` is just about all we need.  +1 good picture :) ..  this will get more people to read your post if you really want help with this.  Also.. mobo model and or system model would be useful.

Comment: Thanks kindly and much appreciteated...having said that, any ideas or thoughts, or workin' on it? Once again much appreciated. It's my first time posting so your feedback is helpful. Thank you.  Oh, and Windows 10 - Dell All in one desktop if that helps :)

Comment: @Señor CMasMas System model is Dell Inspiron 3475 AIO // Baseboard Product: 0XKD8M // Baseboard Version: A00 - hope this helps...I've done a system update and nothing. Thanks man.

Comment: I would suggest that it is somehow hardware disabled by something on the keyboard.  I myself would boot a linux live disk and see if the bluetooth still works from another operating system.  Also, check your EFI firmware (some wrongly call this BIOS) on boot an make sure it is still enabled there.

Comment: Señor CMasMas appreciate your help, but that sounds like other language :( (and I know it is) Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do all that. Thanks anyways though, I do appreciate it.